How to calculate the CPU utilization of block submission?
I'm using the following code from the IOTA SDK github page as my base for a project to calculate the submission time and CPU utilization percentage of a block submission.
Code for block submission
However, I start thinking that I don't calculate the CPU accurately.
Here is how I do it so far. I am aware that the following approach calculates the CPU percentage for the whole system. I have tried to make it process specific but it always returns 0.0. I'd appreciate alternative approaches or corrections on how to do it correctly.
cpu_start = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=None)
client.build_and_post_block(secret_manager=None, tag=tag_hex, data=data_hex)
cpu_end = psutil.cpu_percent(interval=None)

# Calculate CPU usage for this block
cpu_utilization = cpu_end - cpu_start

EDIT:
I applied the suggestion mentioned in the comments. Is it a more accurate and correct approach?
process = psutil.Process()

cpu_start = process.cpu_times()
start_time = time.time()

client.build_and_post_block(secret_manager=None, tag=tag_hex, data=data_hex)

cpu_end = process.cpu_times()
end_time = time.time()

elapsed_time = end_time - start_time

cpu_usage_user = cpu_end.user - cpu_start.user
cpu_usage_system = cpu_end.system - cpu_start.system
cpu_utilization = cpu_usage_user + cpu_usage_system
                    
num_cores = psutil.cpu_count(logical=True)
cpu_utilization_percentage = (cpu_utilization / (elapsed_time * num_cores)) * 100


cpu_percent is not cumulative, rather a snapshot in time. I'd use cpu_times and relate its difference manually to the elapsed time (and possibly the number of CPU cores if you expect 100% to be the whole system and not one core).

@mihi Thank you for your response! I applied your suggestion in the post. I suppose that's the approach you mean?

Looks good to me.
